# Meaning of ように in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> 吉野家は「私たちが出した広告ではありません」と話しています。そして、うその広告に書いてあるアドレスにメールを送らない**ように**言っています。
>   Yoshinoya say that "It's not an advert that we put out". And, they are saying it **so that** you don't send mail to the address that is written in the fake advert.

I'm sure I must have mis-translated ように here because my translation sounds like a very strange thing to say. The only other translation of ように I know is 'like'/'in a way that' etc. which seems to make even less sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「(Verb Phrase) + ように言{い}う」

means:

> "to tell (someone) to (verb phrase)"

Thus,

「メールを送{おく}らないように言っています」 means:

"**is/has been telling (us/everyone) not to send mail**"

This 「よう（に）」 is ***extremely useful*** because, besides 「言う」, you can use it with any verbs that express requests, orders, recommendations, suggestions, advice, etc.