# What is this よう doing behind the verb?

Tags: grammar

For full context:
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20180306/k10011353421000.html?utm_int=news_contents_news-main_001

The sentence in question:
新燃岳で爆発的な噴火が起きたのは、７年前の平成２３年以来で、気象庁は、噴火警戒レベル３を継続し、大きな噴石や火砕流に警戒する**よう**呼びかけています。

I would translate the part surrounding よう as "...they called out that one shall pay attention to great cinders and pyroclastic flow."
But I never saw よう used in this way.

Comment: A recent related question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57074/the-meaning-of-%e3%82%88%e3%81%86-in-this-sentence/57075#57075

Comment: Highly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43427/meaning-of-%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%ab-in-this-sentence

Comment: ` "I never saw よう used in this way."` Really?  I wonder how long you have been studying Japanese, then.

Comment: Well, no grammar so far told me that よう can be used instead of ように for this kind of construction. And I've only been reading not-adapted japanese texts for about 2 months so far, so I didn't encounter this case before.

Answer (score 0):

without よう it's incomplete.  よう used to connect two parts of sentence like "to" in English, in "asked to do" form.